# Edit a post made in multiple languages

Tags: facebook

Our Facebook page is set up in two languages. However, once posted I can't seem to be able to edit the post in the second language. Even if I switch default language and click edit it only shows up in the first language.

Any help?

Comment: please? How can this be so difficult???